# SDF: How to fix a model to the world?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

So I've set up an arm model in an SDF file and have input correct values for mass, CoM, and inertia tensor, but am having trouble figuring out how to fix the arm to the world. I have tried giving the base of the arm an arbitrarily high mass, but this does not seem to work well. I figure that there must be a method to hold the base of the arm static relative to the default ground_plane in the gazebo world but can't seem to figure it out. All solutions seem to be using URDF, which I am not.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20081/sdf:-how-to-fix-a-model-to-the-world?/) by [pbelanger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6047/pbelanger/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured out what I was doing wrong here. When I tried to specify a link to the world, I didn't specify the model name.

A link like the following will prevent the link named `base` of a model named `arm` from moving relative to the world:

```
<link name="world_fix">
    <parent>world</parent>
    <child>arm::base</child>
</link>
```

Placing this in the root of your `<model>` will then prevent the base from moving.

---

Originally posted by [pbelanger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6047/pbelanger/) with karma: 1 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maksymczech](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6341/maksymczech/) on 2018-09-11**:
Shouldn't it rather be a fixed type joint, as described in this tutorial? http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf